# VBScript to test ping latency, and run another VBScript (have this part) if it exceeds a certain point

Tags: vbscript

Backstory: I work for my ISP in Australia, wholesale network provider is congested, no immediate resolution, PPPoE reconnect on my ADSL connection temporarily fixes the problem (effectively we have to constantly reboot the modem or latency spikes to 3000ms+)

So far, I've managed to write a VBScript to telnet into my modem, login, and reset the WAN, which offers the same relief as rebooting the modem (new radius authenticattion session and WAN IP)

```
Option explicit
Dim oShell
set oShell= Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "telnet"
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.Sendkeys "open 192.168.1.1~"
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.Sendkeys "admin~"
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.Sendkeys "wan adsl reset~"
WScript.Sleep 7000
oShell.Sendkeys "exit~"
WScript.Sleep 2000
oShell.Sendkeys "q~"
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.Sendkeys "q~"
Wscript.Quit
```

What I'm now looking to do, is get another script running constantly, that will ping google's DNS 8.8.8.8, and if say 10 consecutive pings have latency over 1000ms or so, to run the script I've already written to perform said PPPoE reconnect. (that script already works on it's own)

Ideally, the script would idle/sleep for approx. 30 seconds while running the reboot script, and then resume it's ping tests (want it to run constantly, not finish after executing the reboot script)

Once I have the script running, my intention is to have this running constantly on a windows virtual machine (that side of things I can handle once the script's operational)

My problem is, I'm not much of a programmer, I've searched online to no avail (only scripts to output to CSV or txt files) and haven't had much luck tweaking or cannibalizing what scripts I could find online.

Could somebody with more coding experience than myself perhaps assist with this? Thanks in advance for anybody's input =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this post didn't attract much attention, but I managed to get a solution in place and thought I'd share on the rare chance it's useful to someone.

At the very least, it can be tweaked to do modem reboots if other symptoms occur such as packet loss or other latency problems. You'll also have to tweak the code to match your modem IP address and telnet login password.

Should also note, that if you can't log into your modem and perform reboots etc. via telnet (test this in command prompt after enabling "telnet client" on your windows computer, google that if you need to), this code won't work. I'm using a TP-Link 8817 which supports this.

As stated in the notes of the code, I wrote this code with the intention of running it in a Windows Virtual Machine. For that reason, it's written in VBScript. If in a different programming language and tweaked slightly, I could see this easily running on a linux router. Heck, I don't know enough to be certain but this may work on a windows server edition straight up.

I hope this helps somebody.

The code:

```
'#####################################################################
'#This VBScript will continually ping a destination of choice        #
'#If 10 consecutive packets are received OK                          #
'#Will sleep 10 seconds and pings again                              #
'#If 10 consecutive packets are lost, or have latency over 2000ms    #
'#Will open shell, telnet into modem and reset WAN connection        #
'#Will then sleep 60 seconds for re-auth with ISP and resume pinging #
'#                                                                   #
'#Intended use in Windows VM so PC use won't interrupt Sendkeys input#
'#If in different programming language, could run on my linux router #
'#If done, re-auth method (Else function) would need to be changed   #
'#                                                                   #
'#A 24/7 ping uses 165.888Mb quota per month upload+download         #
'#Estimating minus in-code "sleep" time could use ~100mb depending   #
'#####################################################################

Option Explicit

Dim strHost
strHost = "8.8.8.8"

'#Define destination for ping test

PingForever strHost

Sub PingForever(strHost)

    Dim Output, Shell, strCommand, ReturnCode

    Set Output = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Shell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")

    strCommand = "ping -n 10 -w 2000 " & strHost

'#Threshold of 10 consecutive pings with 2000ms response time

    While(True)
        ReturnCode = Shell.Run(strCommand, 0, True)     
        If ReturnCode = 0 Then
            WScript.Sleep 10000 

'#If within above threshold, waits 10 seconds before resuming ping test

        Else
        Dim oShell
        set oShell= Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

            oShell.Run "telnet"
            WScript.Sleep 1000
            oShell.Sendkeys "open 192.168.1.1~"
            WScript.Sleep 1000
            oShell.Sendkeys "admin~"
            WScript.Sleep 1000
            oShell.Sendkeys "wan adsl reset~"
            WScript.Sleep 10000
            oShell.Sendkeys "exit~"
            WScript.Sleep 3000
            oShell.Sendkeys "q~" 
            WScript.Sleep 1000
            oShell.Sendkeys "q~"
            WScript.Sleep 60000

'#If outside threshold, open shell, telnet into modem and reset WAN
'#Then close shell and wait 60sec for ISP re-authentication

    End If
        Wscript.Sleep 1000
    Wend
    wScript.echo "Script Ended? :("

'#Script shouldn't end if running as intended, basically an error message

End Sub
```

Comment: Also to end the program, go to task manager -> processes and look for wscript.exe and end the process =)